# MediaRecorder prepare failed: -2147483648 for nougat

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm writing an application to record video from camera through surface.

Following code is for preparing MediaRecorder.

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFilename);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting outfile(videoFilename) like this,

```
File defaultExternalFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File videoFolder = new File(defaultExternalFolder, "My-Vids");
    if (!videoFolder.exists()) {
        videoFolder.mkdir();
    }

String timestemp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String prepend = "MyVid_" + timestemp + "_";
File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", videoFolder);
videoFilename = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
return videoFile;
```

videoSize is nothing but a Object Size class.

When I try to initiate MediaRecorder I get `java.io.IOException: prepare failed.`

Strange thing is It's crashing in Nougat OS only, in other devices It's working correctly.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same issue. It fails only on nougat.

Comment: No I've not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are running this code on emulator. Actually MediaRecorder is not supported on emulator.
see:[MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

> Note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator.

Well, you can test that by comment Mic config and you will see its working.

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
//mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFilename);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
//mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
try {
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tested your code on Android 7.1 ( Samsung Galaxy S8 ) and its working. Issue on emulator only.

Comment: Yea that was the issue, but it's still not working on Samsung phones. Specifically for Front facing camers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the MediaRecorder -2147483648 error
was device and OS level dependent. Usually, the recorder
would start 1 time and subsequent starts would fail.
The fix was to add a call to MediaRecorder.release().

```
...
try {
      audioRecorderType_MR.stop();
      audioRecorderType_MR.release();  // <<-- ADD THIS LINE
} catch (Exception e) {
      J42CallerId.printStackTrace(new J42ProgramCheck("J42VM0072E:", e));
}
audioRecorderType_MR = null;
...
```